# Pandas update sql

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas

Is there any way to do an SQL update-where from a dataframe without iterating through each line? I have a postgresql database and to update a table in the db from a dataframe I would use psycopg2 and do something like:

```
con = psycopg2.connect(database='mydb', user='abc', password='xyz')
cur = con.cursor()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    sql = 'update table set column = %s where column = %s'
    cur.execute(sql, (row['whatver'], row['something']))
con.commit()
```

But on the other hand if im either reading a table from sql or writing an entire dataframe to sql (with no update-where), then I would just use pandas and sqlalchemy. Something like:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:pswd@mydb')
df.to_sql('table', engine, if_exists='append')
```

It's great just having a 'one-liner' using to_sql. Isn't there something similar to do an update-where from pandas to postgresql? Or is the only way to do it by iterating through each row like i've done above. Isn't iterating through each row an inefficient way to do it?

Comment: Can you write the dataframe to a temp table with `to_sql` and then do the UPDATE in postgresql?

Answer (score 85):

Consider a temp table which would be exact replica of your final table, cleaned out with each run:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:pswd@mydb')
df.to_sql('temp_table', engine, if_exists='replace')

sql = """
    UPDATE final_table AS f
    SET col1 = t.col1
    FROM temp_table AS t
    WHERE f.id = t.id
"""

with engine.begin() as conn:     # TRANSACTION
    conn.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Alternatively, "REPLACE INTO final_table (SELECT * FROM temp_table)" which will update all columns (and insert new ones) based on the unique key of the final_table.

Comment: Does Postgres support `REPLACE INTO`?

Comment: @cqcn1991, You will have to add `final_col = temp_col` clauses in `UPDATE` for each column. Here shows only one column. Then the action can be run all at once.

Comment: I am looking to solve the same problem. When I try using this sql string I get MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near. How would it look like in 2019?

Comment: @GeorgiIvanovDimitrov ... this is a Postgres solution. MySQL does not use `FROM` in `UPDATE` queries. It does use `UPDATE ... JOIN`. Read into docs, tutorials, even SO posts.

Answer (score 15):

It looks like you are using some external data stored in `df` for the conditions on updating your database table.  If it is possible why not just do a one-line sql update?

If you are working with a smallish database (where loading the whole data to the python dataframe object isn't going to kill you) then you **can** definitely conditionally update the dataframe after loading it using `read_sql`.  Then you can use a keyword arg `if_exists="replace"` to replace the DB table with the new updated table.

```py
df = pandas.read_sql("select * from your_table;", engine)

#update information (update your_table set column = "new value" where column = "old value")
#still may need to iterate for many old value/new value pairs
df[df['column'] == "old value", "column"] = "new value"

#send data back to sql
df.to_sql("your_table", engine, if_exists="replace")
```

Pandas is a powerful tool, where limited SQL support was just a small feature at first.  As time goes by people are trying to use pandas as their only database interface software.  I don't think pandas was ever meant to be an end-all for database interaction, but there are a lot of people working on new features all the time.  See: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues

Comment: Is the table dropped and recreated within a transaction?  After glancing at the [to_sql() source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/sql.py), I think the answer is "no," but I'm not sure. My concern is that there with be a moment when other users might attempt to query the table and find that it does not exist.

Comment: It will drop the table if the attribute of to_sql() method is set to " if_exists='replace' ". So in this example, yes. See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: The problem with this is that it will have to delete all depending views as well.

Comment: The fact that `if_exists = "replace"` is droped also means the constraints of the table and the data types set in the database are lost and replaced automatically which is not a desirable behavious in most cases.

Answer (score 9):

I have so far not seen a case where the pandas sql connector can be used in any scalable way to *update* database data. It may have seemed like a good idea to build one, but really, for operational work it just does not scale.

What I would recommend is to dump your entire dataframe as CSV using

```
df.to_csv('filename.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Then loading the CSV into the database using [COPY](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/COPY) for PostgreSQL or [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) for MySQL.

If you do not make other changes to the table in question while the data is being manipulated by pandas, you can just load into the table.

If there are concurrency issues, you will have to load the data into a staging table that you then use to update your primary table from.

In the later case, your primary table needs to have a datetime which tells you when the latest modification to it was so you can determine if your pandas changes are the latest or if the database changes should remain.

Assuming you're using the psycopg2 driver with postgres you can skip writing the file to disk by writing to a buffer and feeding that to COPY via STDIN. cur here is a psycopg2 cursor.

```py
from io import StringIO

out_io = StringIO()
df.to_csv(out_io, sep=",", header=False, index=False, na_rep="NULL")
out_io.seek(0)
cols = [f'"{c}"' for c in df.columns]
cur.copy_expert(
        f"COPY {dest_tbl} ({', '.join(cols)}) FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV, NULL 'NULL', ENCODING 'UTF-8')",
        out_io,
    )
```

Be aware that I'm interpolating trusted values in the SQL if you can't trust your data this would be a security risk.

Comment: It's certainly more scalable, but more difficult too)) cause we have to consider the CSV delivery way)

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering why donnt you update the df first based on your equation and then store the df to the database, you could use if_exists='replace', to store on the same table.

Answer (score 1):

I try the first answer and find it works not so well, then I change some parts to pass all situation by using pandas+sqlalchemy to update.

```py
def update_to_sql(self, table_name, key_name)
    a = []
    self.table = table_name
    self.primary_key = key_name
    for col in df.columns:
        if col == self.primary_key:
            continue
        a.append("f.{col}=t.{col}".format(col=col))
    df.to_sql('temporary_table', self.sql_engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
    update_stmt_1 = "UPDATE {final_table} AS f".format(final_table=self.table)
    update_stmt_2 = " INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM temporary_table) AS t ON t.{primary_key}=f.{primary_key} ".format(primary_key=self.primary_key)
    update_stmt_3 = "SET "
    update_stmt_4 = ", ".join(a)
    update_stmt_5 = update_stmt_1 + update_stmt_2 + update_stmt_3 + update_stmt_4 + ";"
    print(update_stmt_5)
    with self.sql_engine.begin() as cnx:
        cnx.execute(update_stmt_5)
```

Comment: Can you add a description regarding what your code does?

Comment: "sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "INNER"
LINE 1: UPDATE test AS f INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM temporary_table.." what db you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that I found to be somewhat clean. This utilizes sqlalchemy. It  only updates one column at a time but can easily be generalized.

```py
def dataframe_update(df, table, engine, primary_key, column):
  md = MetaData(engine)
  table = Table(table, md, autoload=True)
  session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
  for _, row in df.iterrows():
    session.query(table).filter(table.columns[primary_key] == row[primary_key]).update({column: row[column]})
  session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the column names have not changed I prefer removing all rows and then appending the data to the now empty table. Otherwise, dependent views will have to be regenerated as well:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import MetaData

engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://postgres:{pw}@localhost:5432/table')   

# Get main table and delete all rows
# without deleting the table
meta = MetaData(engine)
meta.reflect(engine)
table = meta.tables['table']
del_st = table.delete()

conn = engine.connect()
res = conn.execute(del_st)

# Insert new data    
df.to_sql('table', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to avoid the explicit iteration  by using a SQLAlchemy [update](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_update.html#the-update-sql-expression-construct) statement.

Let's say we have a database table with two columns, `name` and `value`:

```py
# Setup
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)

tbl = sa.Table(
    't31988322',
    sa.MetaData(),
    sa.Column('name', sa.String),
    sa.Column('value', sa.Integer),
)
tbl.create(engine)

# Insert values so we have
# | name | value |
# |------|-------|
# |  a   |  1    |
# |  b   |  1    |
# |  c   |  1    |

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(sa.insert(tbl), [{'name': n, 'value': 1} for n in 'abc'])
```

Let's also say we have this dataframe:

```py
#   name  value
# 0    a      2
# 1    b      4

data = [{'a': n, 'b': v} for (n, v) in zip('ab', [2, 4], strict=True)]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

To update rows in the table with the corresponding values from the dataframe, we convert the dataframe to a list of dicts, and tell SQLAlchemy how to map the dataframe columns to database columns using bindparams:

```py
with engine.begin() as conn: # This context manager automatically commits changes
    conn.execute(
        sa.update(tbl)
        .where(tbl.c.name == sa.bindparam('a'))
        .values(value=sa.bindparam('b')),
        df1.to_dict('records'),
    )
```

Note however that a bindparam's cannot be the same as the name of the database column, so if any of the dataframe's column names match those of the table we must change them, for example:

```py
# Say df has columns "name" and "value"
df2 = df.rename(columns={'name': 'name_', 'value': 'value_'})

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(
        sa.update(tbl)
        .where(tbl.c.name == sa.bindparam('name_'))
        .values(value=sa.bindparam('value_')),
        df2.to_dict('records'),
    )
```