# How to update records in db2 using tuple using python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, db2

I have to update records in db2 after pre processing in python pandas. I am using loop to iterate and update

I have tried updating row by row after creating my update query which works, but it takes time as I have more than 2.5 million records to update.

```
sql_update = "UPDATE ADWREMD6.D_SITUATION_DIST SET ADWLOADID=?, ADWMODDTTM=?, AGENTNAME=?,HOSTNAME=?,AGENTCODE=?,SITUATIONNAME=?, ENVIRONMENT=?, JVM=?,SITDISTDATE=?,MWDATE=?,PSERIESDATE=? WHERE (HOSTNAME=?AND SITUATIONNAME =? AND ENVIRONMENT=?)" 

stmt1 = ibm_db.prepare(cnn, sql_update)
for index,item in df.iterrows():
    try:
        ibm_db.execute(stmt1, (item[0],item[1],item[2],item[3],item[4],item[5],item[6],item[7],item[8],item[9],item[10] ,item[3],item[5],item[6] ))
        j=j+1
    except Exception as ex1:
        jerr=jerr+1
        #print (ex1)
        pass
```

I would like to update query to be written using tuple as it will be faster or any other result which can give me desired solution to execute faster. Thank You

Comment: [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40746465/4858908)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know python, but can you insert all the data needed for the update into a temporary table, then UPDATE all rows using a join to that temp table in a single statement?