# How to trigger update SQL from Python on Redshift database

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sql-update, amazon-redshift

I have redshift database to which I need to fire an update SQL.

Connection string `cnx = create_engine(postgres_str)`.

**Update SQL**

```
UPDATE application_summary
SET invoice_rejection = TRUE
WHERE upper(carrier_name) = 'WEX'
AND only_approval = 0
AND invoice_number = :processed_invoice
```

The Input for the Update SQL **(processed_invoice)** from a dataframe column.

```
df['processed_invoice']
 A12BL
 C123N
 N098V
 x901H
```

How to do I fire the SQL code from Python to update the table?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your DataFrame as a temporary table, and then do a conditional update using that table. Example usage is in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40746465/1680826).