# Update SQL database with dataframe content

Tags: python

I have a pandas dataframe containing two columns: ID and MY_DATA. I have an SQL database that contains a column named ID and some other data. I want to match the ID of the SQL database column to the rows of the dataframe ID column and update it with a new column MY_DATA.
So far I used the following:

```
import sqlite3

df = pd.read_csv('my_filename.csv')
con = sqlite3.connect('my_database.sqlite')
cur = con.cursor()
for row in cur.execute('SELECT ID FROM main;'):
   for i in len(df):
       if (row[i] == df.ID.iloc[i]):
          update_sqldb(df, i)
```

However, I think this way of having two nested for-loops is probably ugly and not very pythonic. I thought that maybe I should use the map() function, but is this the right direction to go?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: I would write the df content in a temporary table and run an "update" SQL-statement which updates the permanent table based on the data from the temp table.

Comment: Ok drum, this shows how to write an SQL database from a dataframe, fine. But here the question is how do I insert only matching data from a dataframe into a pre-existing SQL database (with extra content not in the dataframe).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas update sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988322/pandas-update-sql)

Comment: Don't update. Instead delete all the existing rows and insert the new ones.