# How to write pandas dataframe into snowflake using joins?

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

My snowflake table **(CPG.PRODUCT)** looks like this

| UPC | ML1 | POPULATION | ZIPCODE | CITY | ML2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | NaN | 1456 | 16454 | boston | NaN |
| 1002 | NaN | 1345 | 16556 | new york | NaN |
| 1003 | NaN | 1678 | 15446 | boston | NaN |
| 1005 | NaN | 1665 | 15422 | chicago | NaN |

I am converting about table into pandas data frame using snowflake connector and then FILLING  column ML1 and ML2 using external APIs.

My output for API data would be like this

**TABLE (API1)**

| UPC | ML1 | ML2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | FFG | FFG |
| 1002 | GGF | HHG |
| 1003 | GGF | GGF |
| 1005 | GGF | GGF |

I want to push this data to existing snowflake table (CPG.PRODUCT)

**OUTPUT I WOULD LIKE TO SEE IN SNOWFLAKE**

| UPC | ML1 | POPULATION | ZIPCODE | CITY | ML2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | FFG | 1456 | 16454 | boston | FFG |
| 1002 | GGF | 1345 | 16556 | new york | HHG |
| 1003 | GGF | 1678 | 15446 | boston | GGF |
| 1005 | GGF | 1665 | 15422 | chicago | GGF |

**Can Anyone help me out with this? I am not sure how to write data into snowflake using write_pandas using common rows and columns.**

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I want to insert TABLE (API1) data into (CPG.PRODUCT) using the snowflake python connector.

Comment: So you question is "how to UPDATE a snowflake table via panda dataframes"?

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim yes.

Comment: The lead answer to this question seem to be a valid pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988322/pandas-update-sql

Answer (score 0):

Well here is the SQL query you want:

```sql
INSERT INTO target (UPC, ML1, POPULATION, ZIPCODE, CITY, ML2)
SELECT
    p.UPC,
    a.ML1,
    p.POPULATION,
    p.ZIPCODE,
    p.CITY,
    a.ML2
FROM CPG.PRODUCT p
LEFT JOIN API1 a
    ON a.UPC = p.UPC
ORDER BY
    p.UPC;
```

I used a left join above in case a certain `UPC` in the products table might not match anything in the API table.

Comment: I am not asking for a plain sql query. I want to push TABLE (API1) which is generated in python notebook to the snowflake.

Comment: ...that may be the case, but you still need a query to generate the output table you want to push.

Comment: Updated the question (Look at the comment). What would be the SQL insert statement for this? The condition I am looking for is insert from TABLE(API1) (columns ML1 and ML2) into CPG.PRODUCT where UPC are common btw both tables.