# PostgreSQL NULL

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I'm trying to parse csv and insert it to my local database. Everything is fine until i get an error:

> ERROR:  incorrect syntax for type integer: "None" LINE 1:
> ...workclass, education_num, marital_status) VALUES ('None', NU...

I sure that csv is good, a debug the code and cursor loop for all dataFrame, but after this he sending me this error. Age and education_num is int, workclass and marital_status is varchar. What should i do?

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akmand/datasets/main/adult.csv'
dataFrame = pd.read_csv(url)
print(dataFrame)
try:
    with psycopg2.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="dodle4532",
        password="1111",
        database="firstDataBase"
    ) as connection:
        ex = """INSERT INTO "table" (age, workclass, education_num, marital_status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"""
        for i in range(0, dataFrame.size):
            cursor.execute(ex, (str(dataFrame['age'].get(i + 1)), dataFrame['workclass'].get(i + 1), 
            str(dataFrame['education_num'].get(i + 1)), dataFrame['marital_status'].get(i + 1)))
```

Comment: `str(dataFrame['age'].get(i + 1))` creates `"None"` (as string). Usually you should use `dataFrame['age'].get(i + 1)` and/or use a default value `dataFrame['age'].get(i + 1, default=0)`

Comment: CSV can be insert much faster using the copy protocol. This is also supported by psycopg: https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/copy.html (or https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from )

Comment: @MauriceMeyer this is probably happening as it overruns the last entry in the DataFrame and tries to get a nonexistent row (reviewing the table should make this obvious .. but yuck!) .. however, some values in the DataFrame may truly be `None` and need converting to `"null"`

Answer (score 0):

This is likely related to string interpolation (which needs to be done at some level, but I'd avoid directly passing the values as you are) .. you could patch this to get a basic version by checking for `None` and making it `"null"` (the string) instead

```
entry = member.get(...)
if value is None:
    value = "null"
```

However, Pandas `.to_sql(...)` may do what you want directly, while also being *much* faster
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

```
with psycopg2.connect(...) as connection:
    dataFrame.to_sql("firstDataBase", connection)
```

Comment: what if my csv had 10 column, but sql have first 3 of them? It isn,t working with second method

Comment: assuming you want all the values, you might be able to just append with `if_exists="append"` or clobber the table with the more dangerous `if_exists="replace"` (BEWARE: this will DROP the existing table) .. otherwise you can [fetch the database with `.read_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html), merge the two dataframes locally, and then replace the database table as before .. that said, I'd go further and use a temporary table at least as suggested here with more exotic checking to as-needed/to-taste https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988322/