Avoid creating duplicate records with Python Polars write_database
With polars.DataFrame.write_database, is there a way to avoid creating duplicate records if I import a record multiple times, where some of the data to be imported is updated between imports? I'd like to key on a field--if that field is the same for an existing record and a record to be imported, I'd like to update the existing record with the new information, not create a second record.

Perhaps you could write the data to a temporary table, then update the existing records from that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988322/pandas-update-sql

I don't think it's possible at the moment. It'd be nice if we could have a way to sync data with table in the DB (delete / update / insert). Just out of interest - which database are you using? Is it Postgres / MS SQL / something else?
